# Select Where inside if then else in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select

I have an SQL table with 10 columns along with 20 records. One of the column contains the user name as us_name. I need to filter out the table rows as per current user logged in. For this purpose I am using the following SQL command. Suppose users are `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` and Table name is `ab_cd`.

```
SELECT *
FROM ab_cd
WHERE us_name = 'current_user'
```

It is working perfectly fine. But for user `D`, I want complete table to show as `D` is super user. I need something like this.

```
IF Current_user = 'D'
Then
SELECT *
FROM ab_cd
Else
SELECT *
FROM ab_cd
WHERE us_name = 'current_user'
```

But it is not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: SQL-Server or mysql? That are very diferent DBMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the logical `or` operator to simulate this behavior. Assuming @current_user is a variable holding the username:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ab_cd
WHERE  @current_user = 'd' or us_name = @current_user
```

Of course, this could be shorthanded using the `in` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ab_cd
WHERE  @current_user IN ('d', us_name)
```